# dpkg: error: you must specify packages by their own names, not by quoting the names of the files they come in

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm in need of some help again :-)

I wanted to get my fingerprint sensor working on my HP 470 ProBook. Went through part of the tutorial here: https://balintbanyasz.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/get-validity-vfs-495-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/

I bailed out after converting the RPM to DEB and trying to install it but getting a bunch of warnings. It's not worth the hassle to get my system mangled. It's working fine. Apart from that sensor. Well.... was working fine :-D

Running apt remove doesn't uninstall the package.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all validity-sensor-setup_4.5-119_amd64.deb
```

Gives me the error below:

```
dpkg: error: you must specify packages by their own names, not by quoting the names of the files they come in
```

What do I do now?

Thanks for you advice!

edit 1:
When "dpkg - |grep validity-sensor" is run, it shows:

```
iHR validity-sensor-setup 4.5-119 amd64 Validity Finger Print Service
```

How do I look into a deb file to see what it is doing?

I am using 20.04 btw.

edit 2:
When running

```
sudo apt remove validity-sensor-setup
```

it just says:

```
E: The package validity-sensor-setup needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

edit 3:

When I run

```
sudo dpkg -r remove validity-sensor-setup
```

the terminal reports:

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove remove which isn't installed
dpkg: error processing package validity-sensor-setup (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 validity-sensor-setup
```

edit 4:

This at least gave some more output:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all validity-sensor-setup
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
(Reading database ... 242917 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing validity-sensor-setup (4.5-119) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/validity-sensor-setup.postrm: line 5: sbin/insserv: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package validity-sensor-setup (--remove):
 installed validity-sensor-setup package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 validity-sensor-setup
```

edit 5:

Ok, so when I:

```
sudo dpkg -e validity-sensor-setup_4.5-119_amd64.deb
```

as per here [Another package problem](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/debian9-apt-package-x-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-no-archive-found-4175634338/page2.html#post5880761)

then the subdirectory DEBIAN is created and some files are dropped in that subdirectory. The postrm file contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
export RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX

    sbin/insserv etc/init.d
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated... in the meantime I will try and soldier on.

Comment: When dpkg - |grep validity-sensor is run, it shows:

iHR validity-sensor-setup                                       4.5-119                                                     amd64        Validity Finger Print Service

How do I look into a deb file to see what it is doing?

I am using 20.04 btw.

Comment: Thanks, done that, edited.

Comment: When running sudo apt remove validity-sensor-setup it just says: 
E: The package validity-sensor-setup needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: edited again with the results

Comment: added edit number 5